# How can I replace the 'timeout'?

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo '' 
    echo 'Please run the script as root'
    echo ''
  exit
fi

for run in {1..11}
do  
    echo ''
    echo $run'th running...'    

    echo 'Starting tst script...'
    echo ''
    timeout 30 sudo ./tst.sh  <-----XXXXXX

    # Call next script
    echo ''
    echo 'Sending data...'

    for run in {1..10}
    do  # run 10 times
        sudo /home/ubuntu/Desktop/data/data <----- data.sh          
    done

    echo ''
    echo 'restarting script..."

done
```

The problem is that I want to start the tst.sh and and after 30 seconds I want to stop it. Although the 'timeout 30' is a good solution, the next lines will not be executed. How can I fix this problem so that I can stop after execution the tst.sh and also I execute the following lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to run `tst.sh` as a background process?

Comment: Btw: replace your doube quote by a single quote.

Comment: Search this site for `bash timeout`.

Comment: Actually, it does not matter to run it either as s background or not. For me is important that I run it and then stop, then I execute next lines and so on 11 times

Comment: Your post doesn't include it, but is there a `#!/bin/bash -e` or `set -e` or `set -euo pipefail` anywhere in your script? That would explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It puzzles me how the `timeout 30` is a good solution. If I strip down the script to a bare minimum,

```
echo hop
timeout 2 sudo sleep 20
echo plop
```

and run it with `time bash test.sh`I get:

```
hop
plop

real    0m20.039s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.025s
```

In other words, the lines after the `timeout` get executed (contrary to what you are experiencing), but the `sleep 20` is not killed after 2 seconds.

Anyway, another solution might be:

```
sudo ./tst.sh &
pid=$!
sleep 30
kill $pid
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. OK, but now I have the following problem. I want to kill tst.sh only then, when all lines has been already executed. So, after the line with echo 'restarting script...". Sorry, I gave you wrong info about process killing. I hope that you understand me, what I need to have.

Comment: Basically, you can put the `kill $pid` anywhere in your script. Just make sure that the `pid=$!` is directly after the launching of the `sudo ./tst.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works better for me using the *non-interactive* flag of sudo.

```
     -n, --non-interactive
                 Avoid prompting the user for input of any kind.  If a password is required
                 for the command to run, sudo will display an error message and exit.
```

Basically it won't ask you for password but fail if you don't have sudo already.

```sh
sudo -n -v 2> /dev/null
if [[ "${?}" != "0" ]]; then
    echo '' 
    echo 'Please run the script as root'
    echo ''
fi
```

If you don't redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` you'll get the `sudo: a password is required` message printed out.

The `-v` is to validate and renew your current sudo "session". I use this because it doesn't output anything.